# virtusertable vs. MX-record

Tags: sendmail, virtusertable

I have two mail-servers: A and B.

The server A is the official MX-handler for domain `example.com` and is configured to forward the entire `@example.com` to `someuser@yahoo.com`. This part works fine.

However, some times server B also gets e-mail intended for `foo@example.com` and I'd like it to deliver such mail *directly* to `someuser@yahoo.com`.

To this end I added the same record to `/etc/mail/virtusertable` on server B as I have on server A:

```
@example.com   someuser@yahoo.com
```

I rebuilt the databases and restarted sendmail on B, but I still see it hand off the e-mail for `example.com` to A -- instead of delivering it directly to Yahoo.

It is as if MX-record trumps over the `virtusertable` -- how do I reverse this and save one hop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Virtusertable domains

Sendmail consults virtusertable only for deliveries to local email domains (`$=w`) or special virtual doamins (`$={VirtHost}`).

To list of domains on both list as root use `echo '$=w' |sendmail -bt` and `echo '$={VirtHost}' |sendmail -bt`.  By default list of local email domains is auto-configured/auto-filled.

To add `example.com` to `$={VirtHost}` you may use the following line in `sendmail.mc` file used to generate `sendmail.cf file`:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
CP{VirtHost}example.com
divert(0)dnl comment: Turn off LOCAL_CONFIG
```

Comment: Thanks! I added the `example.com` to `/etc/mail/local-host-names` and now it all works...